# SSRS MDX for Data from previous two weeks

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, lag, olap-cube

I am trying to get the data fromt the present calender week to the previous two weeks. If I specify the date range as parameters in the MDX query, the table gets filled up properly.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[planned_cumulative],[Measures].[Last Forecast CW] } ON   COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { ([Project].[Projekt-Task].[Task].ALLMEMBERS*  { [Date].[Date - CW].[Week].&[2014]&[201420] : [Date].[Date - CW].[Week].&[2014]&[201422]})} ON ROWS FROM [DWH]
```

But if I try and use the lag function, I get an error. Here is the MDX query.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[planned_cumulative],[Measures].[Last Forecast CW] } ON   COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { ([Project].[Projekt-Task].[Task].ALLMEMBERS*  [Date].[DATECW - CW].[Week].CurrentMember.Lag(2) ) } ON ROWS 

FROM [DWH]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query (quite rightly) identifies a range of two weeks, by using two members from the dimension separated by a colon i.e. [Week X] : [Week Y].

Your second query uses the LAG function, which will return a member on your dimension, not a range of members.

Try this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[planned_cumulative],[Measures].[Last Forecast CW] } ON   COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY {[Project].[Projekt-Task].[Task].ALLMEMBERS * TAIL([Date].[Date - CW].[Week],3) } ON ROWS 

FROM [DWH]
```

Also, your first query refers to [Date].[Date - CW].[Week] whereas your second query uses [Date].[DATECW - CW].[Week]. I have gone with the first option as you say that query works.

Let me know if that helps.

Ash

EDIT: Apologies for that. I have amended the query to use the TAIL function, which will give you a number of tuples from a set starting at the end and working backwards. So with TAIL ({Set Of Weeks},3) this should give you the current week and the previous two weeks. I have tested a similar query on my cube and it seems produce the expected results.

Hope that solves it for you.

Ash

Comment: Thanks but I am getting an error :
The currentmember function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1-argument. A member expression was used"

Also the actual week values are under the WEEK hierarchy in the format "CW 21" and so on